# EJS template not loading with two way templates, how to fix that?

Tags: node.js, express, templates, ejs

My source code repo: [link](https://github.com/uday1kiran/blogproj)

contact and create ejs files in views folder are exact copies.

Routing is in index.js

```
app.get('/contact',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('contact')
})

app.get('/posts/new',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('create')
})
```

contact page is loading all styles but create page is not loading the styles and css.
If I change the router from /posts/new to /new then loading.
Please suggest how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small mistake in the `views/layouts/head.ejs` file.

You need to change this line of code from

```
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

to

```
<link href="/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

This will load the `css` for the **create** page as well.

Comment: thank you it is working now.can you suggest what is the error in this. bit.ly/3vn5XuB

Comment: You need to put this inside a try catch block.

Comment: If I update the views, I am getting like this. ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\layouts\head.ejs' But it exists